# Email permissions not working in Facebook through the JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I am trying this script:

```
FB.login({scope: 'email'},function(response){
                if(response.status == 'connected'){
                    alert('I am connected')
                }
            });
```

But it is not asking the user to give permissions on email.. :(

I tried both scope and perms as parameters.

References:

- [Graph API, Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)
- [Facebook authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out your mistake, the signature of the function is FB.login(callback function(), {options}), rest is Okay.

```
FB.login(function(response){
            if(response.status == 'connected'){
                alert('I am connected')
            }
        },{scope: 'email'});
```

reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full working example, just plug in your app id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="getEmail();return false;">Get Email</a>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({ appId: '**AppID**', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml : true });

  function getEmail() {  
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session && response.perms) {
        FB.api('/me',  function(response) {
            alert('Email: ' + response.email);
          }
        );
      }
    } , {scope:'email'}); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for responding, i tried your solution as well, but unfortunately I am unable to ask for email permissions.. :(

Comment: ah! fixed the problem.. see my answer

Comment: :( can't answer right now... they have restriction on repute less than 100. btw your answer is partially correct, just use 'scope' instead of 'perms'